Book series involving a girl in Scotland who finds out she's special, and a boy with Celtic symbols on him who helps her hide
It's about a girl in Scotland, I believe, and she finds out she's really special and she needs to be hidden because people want to take her and use her. (I forget what for; I think her blood is special, but I'm really not sure.) She finds this boy who helps her hide and he has tattoos and Celtic symbols on him and they end up falling in love at the end.
I think there are 2 or 3 books and every book is a Celtic symbol.

In roughly which year/s did you read these books? And did the girl or any other character/s in the books have powers? Was magic a part of the story?

There are some parallels with some of Robert Holdstock's stuff from the 1980s  e.g. Mythago Wood.
